# SQL returning a set of results with a dynamic 'Limit' variable

Tags: sql, web-services, limit

I'm doing a basic webservice which is relating to the following query

```
Select * FROM `Jobs` 
ORDER BY DatePosted
LIMIT 20
```

The webservice returns 20 rows as desired, this will then form a table in my app. However, I need the user to be able to press See More and then return results 20-40 etc. The user should be able to press See More as many times as they want. How can I handle this in my SQL. I'm thinking I will need some sort of additional variable posted up to my web service to handle it but I'm not sure. Any help appreciiated

Answer (score 0):

Actually limit takes two arguments, first is offset so on second query you should use

```
 LIMIT 20,20
```

Comment: so if I want results 40-60 is my LIMIT 40,20? Also I needed to know how to be able to dynamically change the offset

Comment: I figure I can just post up a $counter variable with the web service call? and then slot that into LIMIT $counter,20?